# When groupby is done on a DataFrame, how to get the diff values within for a single group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I am trying to run a `diff` command on the `Revenue`, such that the `diff` gets applied per group `(shop_id,item_id,date)`
I want to do some analysis on the change in `Revenue` per day (per shop and item combination)

[image]

In the current case, the `diff` will be something like below. This `diff` is only for `shop_id(0)+item_id(30)`
For the next group `shop_id(0)+item_id(31)`, the `diff` must be created again.

[image]

Please help me to do this.

Regards
Sachin

Comment: hey Sachin, can you provide a textual example of your dataframe?

Comment: looking to see the trends in revenue, for a specific shop and specific item. But the point is diff() command is unable to differentiate that the shop/item has changed.